# Rails 3 namespaced routes: how to link *from* a namespace back to the global namespace? [REVISED]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces

I have a common layout file, used site-wide.  It contains links like:

```
<%= link_to("Home", { :controller => :home, :action => :index }) %>
```

And other common links in the header/footer etc.

All of my controllers are simply under the `app/controllers/` directory.  But I've added a namespace for admins (to ban users etc):

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

My admin namespace isn't any different in look & feel, so it uses the same layout as the rest of the site.  Which is causing some issues, since all of my `link_to` and `url_for` calls are being mis-interpreted as, say:

```
<%= link_to("Home", { :controller => "admin/home", :action => :index }) %>
```

Which crashes the app, as no such route exists.  Do I have to go through all of my templates used by the layout and change the controller portion of the `link_to` with a leading slash, or is there a better way to make all of my top-level routes functional even under the admin namespace?  I link out of the admin namespace into the top-level namespace for lots of things, so it would be good if I didn't really have to give any special consideration to my `link_to` calls.

In summary, when under a namespaced controller, do you have to prefix all `:controller` parameters in `link_to` with a leading slash in order to break out of the namespace?

Comment: try using '<real resource name>/forums' or even <real resource name>_forums_path (or whatever the named route is. I'm not putting this in an answer because it's just a guess/suggestion.

Comment: But the problem isn't linking to namespaced routes, it's linking to non-namespaced routes from inside a namespaced route, if you catch my drift? :)  It's like you have to prefix all controller names in the links in your layout with a forward slash, e.g. `<%= link_to("Home", { :controller => "/home", :action => :index} %>`, otherwise it will try find a "Home" controller in the admin namespace but not even consider looking in the global namespace.

Comment: you might consider this: http://pandejo.blogspot.com/2009/03/rails-nested-resources-tutorial.html

Comment: My understanding was that if you want to use a controller name different than the one you're conceptually in, you have to be explicit. That's what I really was trying to suggest in my first comment. Having said all that, nested resources might get you where you want to go. Another approach would be to have your users/xxx/edit behave differently depending upon user permissions or role.

Comment: Thanks, I guess just naming all of my routes will help.  I should do this anyway, just from a maintenance/refactoring perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the forums route on the routing and using the forums_path instead of the :controller/:action hash should be enough and cleaner.

config/routes.rb:

```
match '/forums' => 'forums#index', :as => :forums
```

Views:

```
<li class="menuitem"><%= link_to("Forums", forums_path()) %></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually completely rewriting my question while you posted this, since I figured it must have been too badly explained ;)  I think named routes should solve a lot, you're right.  Having some battles with routing, but I think it's just because I'm not used to Rails' way of doing things o_O